# Compute $\int_{|z|=2}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}$ where $f$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I want to compute the following integral:

$\int_{|z|=2}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}$ where $f$ is defined as follows:

$f(z) = 1 + \frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{2!z^2}+\dots+\frac{1}{n!z^n}$

I have already shown that $f$ has no zeros $|z|\geq 2$. Now, I want to use the Argument Principle Theorem.

In order to do this I have to compute the zeros, their multiplicities, the poles and their multiplicities.

But how can I compute the zeros? I only see that $0$ is a pole with multiplicity 9. I tried using the Rouche Theorem but got stuck.

Comment: Hint: write $f=p/q$ with polynomials $p,\,q$ having no common factors (e.g. $q=n!z^n$), so $f'/f=p'/p-q'/q$, the integrate each term separately.

Comment: $0$ is a pole with multiplicity $n$ not $9$

Comment: @wasn'tme The Argument Principle tells me that the integral should equal to (the number of zeros - the number of poles) * $2\pi i$. But there are only $n$ poles. Therefore the integral is $- 2 \pi n$. But according to my solutions I should get $0$.

Comment: There are also $n$ zeros with multiplicity $1$. Since there are no zeros for $2\leq |z|$, and knowing that every polynomial have $n$ complex zeros, then all must lie at $|z|<2$

Comment: @Guillerminho77 What I do not see is how $f$ is a polynomial? I thought that by definition polynomials have only variables raised to the positive power?

Comment: $f$ is not a polynomial, but you can rewrite your function as $f=\frac{P(z)}{n!z^n}$ with $P(z)$ a polynomial that is no zero at $z=0$, and has exaclty the same zeros as $f$

Answer (score 1):

It is an application of Rouché's Theorem. More precisely, it can be shown using the ideas of the proof of Rouché's Theorem.

Let $g(z)=\mathrm{e}^{1/z}$ and $f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!z^k}$.

Clearly, $$
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=2}\frac{f'}{f}\in\mathbb Z
\quad\text{and}\quad
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=2}\frac{g'}{g}\in\mathbb Z.
$$
Hence, if the function
$$
I(t)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=2}\frac{tf'+(1-t)g'}{tf+(1-t)g},
\quad t\in [0,1],
$$
is well-defined and continuous, then it is constant and hence
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=2}\frac{f'}{f}=I(1)=I(0)=
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=2}\frac{g'}{g}=0.
$$

It suffices to show that $|g(z)|>|g(z)-f(z)|$,
for all $|z|=2$. Once this is proven then we shall have that
$$
|tf(z)+(1-t)g(z)|\le |g(z)|-t|g(z)-f(z)|> 0, 
\quad \text{whenever $t\in [0,1],\,\,|z|=2$}.
$$
We have
$$
g(z)-f(z)=\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{k!z^k}
=\frac{1}{(n+1)!z^{n+1}}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1+k)!z^k}
$$
and hence, for $|z|=2$
$$
|g(z)-f(z)|\le
\frac{1}{(n+1)!|z|^{n+1}}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1+k)!|z|^k}
\le \frac{1}{(n+1)!|z|^{n+1}}\mathrm{e}^{1/|z|} =\frac{\mathrm{e}^{½}}{2^{n+1}(n+1)!}.
$$
Meanwhile, also for $|z|=2$
$$
|g(z)|=|\mathrm{e}^{1/z}|\ge \mathrm{e}^{-½} .
$$
Finally, for $n\ge 1$,
$$
\frac{\mathrm{e}^{½}}{2^{n+1}(n+1)!}\le \frac{\mathrm{e}^{½}}{2^{2}2!} =\frac{\mathrm{e}^{½}}{8} <\mathrm{e}^{-½}.
$$

Hence, $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=2}\frac{f'}{f}=0$.